# What determines default Interactive Report column layout in Oracle APEX 5?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have an Interact Report page in Oracle APEX 5 that includes a SQL Query with ~10 columns or so. When I first load the report, the columns are in a certain order, and columns are set to Do Not Display (as seen under `Actions` -> `Select Columns`). The default order does not seem to match the order in which I list them in the SQL Query, nor does it use the order that is found in the `Page Designer`, under `{Page Name}` -> `Regions` -> `Content Body` -> `{Interactive Report}` -> `Columns`. I have two questions about the way columns are displayed in the Interact Report component:

1. What determines the default order of these columns?
2. What determines which columns are set to `Do Not Display` and those set to `Display in Report`?

Are those settings saved for each user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you should probably take a good look at the documentation. Plenty of useful things. The main thing you're looking for in this case would be about [saving interactive reports](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E59726_01/doc.50/e39147/ir_using.htm#HTMDB29011).

In short though.

1. When first having created the IR the columns will be in the same order as in the select statement.
2. Afterwards, there is no longer a relation between position in the select statement or the order of the columns as seen in page designer.
3. Instead, the initial order has been used to create an initial Primary Default report.
4. From this point on, column position and being hidden or display solely depends on the settings in the "Select Columns" menu.
5. If you want to alter the default offered to the end user, you'll have to run the page, alter the IR, and save your settings through Actions > Save Report and selecting Primary Default.

Settings saved for each user? Yes and no. End users will be offered the primary default at first. If multiple defaults are present the application will remember which one they have last been working on when coming back.
Users can also save private versions of reports, or public ones, if enabled.  They can then edit the report settings, but these settings only affect their own report in that same session. If not saved, all changes they made settings-wise are lost and they'll be presented with the defaults again next time they log in. (or perform a reset themselves).
Unless you take all control away of course, by configuring the Actions menu of the IR.

Answer (score 0):

I was hoping to edit saved reports in the Application Builder, but I guess this is not available (at least in 5.1 that I'm using).
This helped me:

```
SELECT FLOW_ID, PAGE_ID, REPORT_ALIAS, STATUS, IS_DEFAULT, DISPLAY_ROWS, REPORT_COLUMNS
  FROM apex_050100.WWV_FLOW_WORKSHEET_RPTS
 WHERE FLOW_ID = 101
   AND page_id = 25
;
```

Then I edited that table updating columns list or other attributes of the saved report.